# specific program runs slowly

Tags: windows-10, python

A specific program I use appears to run very slowly---80% of the time, mouse clicks made within this program window are missed and keyboard presses lag. While this is happening, I can still click anywhere else and open other applications and files without a problem. Edit: To clarify what I mean by "80% of the time." I don't necessarily mean that 8/10 mouse clicks are missed or 8/10 keyboard presses take 3 seconds to register, but more like, the program will run perfectly fine for 20 min and then have issues for 80min. Not quite that cleanly but closer to what I mean; so, the issues seem to crop up in blocks of time but I don't see a pattern.

I know this is vague but I am hoping someone can point me in the right direction.

The program is PsychoPy, a program with a GUI that allows me to set up experiments and then compiles what I made using python. Never have an issue using the GUI, only when I run the script. I am on a dell desktop running windows 10 Enterprise.

Thanks!

Comment: Is the program written in Python, or it just compiles what you give it into Python?

Comment: The best persons to ask are the authors...

Comment: @freginold The window where the issues arise is definitely written in python. the PsychoPy GUI I use to build the code....I'm pretty sure that is also generated using python.

Comment: @xenoid I'm trying to get in contact with them. They're professors/researchers that maintain a forum where they volunteer their time to answer a lot of questions and help trouble-shoot. I haven't received a response in some time so I started seeking help elsewhere. I'll give it another shot in a week.

Comment: @xenoid I should also mention, I've started thinking that the issue is with windows 10 enterprise, perhaps an automatic update, because a psychopy file I used in March worked perfectly fine then but doesn't now and I haven't updated Psychopy.